# How to make a single page HTML website render faster

Tags: javascript, html, seo

My question is bit general , I have a website

[ide-global.com](http://www.ide-global.com)

So this is a single page website , Since it has large content the size of the website is increasing more than `98kb` which is according to specification much more than the limit and results into slower rendering .

Can any one suggest any plugin that I can apply on this to make it load Asynchronously .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So based on the inspection I did on your site, I got these points:

1. Your page has more than 25 external javascript files and more than 10 external css files. Combine them in one js and one css file.
2. You have not enabled gzip compression on the files. This will reduce load more than 50%.
3. You should put css files on top. there are two files which you should include on top.

   http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway400,200
   http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

These should increase the performance of your website.
For plugins, there are many options which give you an insight about your site performance and suggestions to improve them but they won't improve your site performance directly. For eg.

1. Yslow extension for chrome and firefox
2. Page speed extension

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

For me you have two huge problems:

- **Number of requests**: A browser is limited in th number of parallel request it can do. Optimizations for this should be (in this order):

  - Check of not needed dependencies
  - Check what can be loaded latter
  - combine js and css in one file of each type.
- **File size**: You have a few huge files [1.3 MB background image](http://www.ide-global.com/images/promotions/promo-one-bg.jpg), [660k video](http://www.ide-global.com/video/web_ide.mp4)

  - For the video, this is lost bandwidth. This can be done with 1k of js and 10k of images. In addition the current video is blurry.
  - You need to compress your images. Some images could be 10 time smaller without visual loss. Search for image optimizers online, there are ton of them.
  - Activate gzip on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**There are numbers of possibilities which slow down your website**

1. **Web request**

   - A browser can  make 20 parallel downloading request from a domain.
     so you need to avoid useless requests.

   **FIX**

   You can use fontawesome in place of your icon images, you can also combined your images into single spritesheet.
2. **Avoid render blocking**

   - You have to load your all .js with async call that will remove your .js render blocking.
3. **You can use CDN**

   - CDN is a content delivery network which copy all your static resources to its different servers globally so that the data can easily reach to the client computer.

Here is just an overview, there are many more things you need to do in order to make your website really faster.